# What's the difference between "5.0f" and "5.f" in C++?

Tags: c++, numbers, comparison, difference

I've seen both of them being used, but I never realized the difference between them. What's the difference ?

Comment: you should google this rather than posting it on SO.

Answer (score 3):

None. 5.f is just a shorter form of 5.0f (or 5.0000f, ...).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any. They are equivalent.

There are lots of other ways to express the same `float` literal in C++ (`5.00f`, `5e0f`, `5.e+0f` etc).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference 5.f=5.0f=5.00f=5.000f=5.0000f etc

Answer (score 0):

They are prety much the same. It will just help you in code readability.

Comment: Does "pretty much the same" mean "exactly the same"? Or is there a difference?